# Relations between order of elements in $SL(2,F)$ and $PSL(2,F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, projective-space

Is there a relation between the order of an element in $SL(2,F)$ (where F is a finite field) and that of its projection down to $PSL(2,F)$ ?

For example: if $x$ has order 4 in $SL(2,F)$, its image under the canonical projection has order 2 in $PSL(2,F)$. 
Is it correct to say that the order of the image would be one of the prime divisors of the order of the lift ?

Thanks so much for any guide.

Comment: No that would not be correct. That would imply that all elements of ${\rm PSL}(2,F)$ had prime order, which is not true.

Comment: @Derek Holt So say for example, $x$ has order 5 in $SL(2,F)$, then what would be the possible orders for $\pi(x)$ in $PSL(2,F)$ ?

Comment: In that case the only possible order would be $5$. If $n$ is the order in ${\rm SL}(2,F)$ then the possible orders in ${\rm PSL}(2,F)$ are $n$ and $n/2$.